# electricsheep screensaver won't start

Tags: 11.04, screensaver

After the installation of electricsheep, the screensaver won't work: it starts fading to black then, when it should display the screensaver, it suddenly goes back to desktop.
I read that disabling compiz should fix this behaviour but I don't want to go 2d-unity.
I'm using Natty.
Any suggestion?

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-get-electric-sheep-to-work-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a whole lot of posts talking about this kind of problem: it doesn't seems to be related to electrisheep but to gnome-screensaver itself.

I tried with some stock screensavers experiencing the same behaviour: I then installed XScreenSaver and it works like a charm (googling for how to use electricsheep with XScreenSaver it wasn't that hard...)

How-to:

1. open a terminal and `sudo aptitude install xscreensaver electricsheep`
2. open "startup applications", click "add" and put as a command `xscreensaver -nosplash`
3. open ~/.xscreensaver (`gedit ~/.xscreensaver`): at the bottom of the screensaver's list you'll have to add `GL:               electricsheep --root 1              \n\`
   , otherwise you'll not be able to see it in xscreensaver
4. in a terminal or via <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> write  `xscreensaver-demo` to set it up: you can also manage your power saving settings
5. log out and log back in (or reboot)

Comment: Can you include the basic instructions for your solution in your answer?

Comment: @jrg: added instructions: thanks for the advice!